# Reason for duplicate keys on http post?

Tags: http, http-post

Reading about [Http Post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) on Wikipedia it states that This is a format for encoding key-value pairs with possibly duplicate keys. Is this correct and if so what is the reasoning? Why would a client ever post duplicate keys and if a duplicate key is posted how is the correct corresponding value returned on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit multiple values for the same thing.

In PHP, for example, you can name multiple input fields `somedata[]`. All values of the input boxes are then put in an array named `somedata`.